# Can the dual of a concave problem be an LP/QP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

Is it possible in general for the dual problem of a concave minimization problem to be a convex LP/QP?

Specifically, can the concave minimization problem
$$
\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} -\lVert x\rVert_1
$$
be rewritten as a convex LP/QP in any way, either using duality of with some other tricks?

Comment: Note that the objective function is not bounded from below.

Comment: Suppose the dual were an LP.  Now what type of problem is the dual of the dual?

Comment: It's always the case that the Lagrangian dual of a minimization problem is a concave maximization problem.  In general, if the primal problem is nonconvex, then there's no guarantee of strong duality.